# capture DataGridViewComboCell answer change event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a DataGridViewComboCell in a DataGridView.

I need to know when the user has clicked one of the selections in that combo cell.

I can't find an event that fires when this happens.

For most of the events with names that sound like they will do this, they don't do anything until the user changes focus.

I don't know why Microsoft waits for users to change focus to do something. I certainly don't expect this behavior. The QA staff assigned to me sure doesn't.

I can't believe Clicked() doesn't fire when someone clicks this. Neither does ContentClicked or the other clicked methods.

Here are all the events I've tried: CellContentClick, CellEndEdit, SelectionChanged, Click, 
CellStateChanged, CellClick, CellValueChanged.

None of them change until the user changes focus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`. You have to find that event in the `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl`, like this:

```
//EditingControlShowing event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e){
  ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
  if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == column_you_want){
     combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
     combo.SelectedIndexChanged += combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
  }
}
private void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //....
}
```

Comment: Excellent! It behaves exactly as I want. I would think this should be the *normal* case. I don't understand why MS buried access to the combo box like that without surfacing a handy change event.

Comment: @micahhoover maybe it's not used frequently, however anyway exposing that event is more convenient.